# Uncountability of basis of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

Given vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ such that the elements of $V$ are infinite-tuples. How to show that any basis of it is uncountable?

Comment: How do you define "infinite $n$-tuple?" What is $n$? Do you just mean elements which are infinite sequences of real numbers?

Comment: For example (a_1,a_2,...) would be an element of V,where each a_i is a real number.

Comment: Then you don't mean $n$-tuple, which means a sequence $n$ real numbers.

Comment: Based on literature which I have read it can be called n-tuple as well.

Comment: No. n-tuple means length n, e.g. 3-tuple (5,2,7). For your things you might say "infinite tuple", or "countably infinite tuple", although as already pointed out the term "sequence" is more in use.

Comment: Let $V$ be the vector space with just one element, namely the sequence $(0,0,0,0,\ldots)$. Then the elements of $V$ are certainly infinite tuples, but $V$ has a finite (in fact empty) basis.

Comment: There is a technical difference here @Pilot The sequences you are considering fall under $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ whereas by $\infty$-tuple, most people refer to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ which are sequences which are eventually zero. The first is uncountable while the second countable.

Comment: My bad. Let me clarify it then: V contains all possible infinite tuples.

Comment: @Pilot As several people have mentioned, it's probably best to not use the term "tuple". I would just stick with "infinite sequence of real numbers".

Comment: I found an older question, which is a generalization of this one: [Vector dimension of a set of functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95028/vector-dimension-of-a-set-of-functions)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: [What is the standard proof that $\dim(k^{\mathbb N})$ is uncountable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176475/what-is-the-standard-proof-that-dimk-mathbb-n-is-uncountable/)

Answer (score 5):

Take any [almost disjoint family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets) $\mathcal A$ of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.
Construction of such set is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162387/countable-set-having-uncountably-many-infinite-subsets).

I.e. for any two set $A,B\in\mathcal A$ the intersection $A\cap B$ is finite.

Notice that 
$$\{\chi_A; A\in\mathcal A\}$$
is a subset of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ which has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

We will show that this set is linearly independent. This implies that the base must have cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$. (Since every independent set is contained in a basis - this can be shown using Zorn lemma. You can find the proof in many places, for example [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn1.pdf) on applications of Zorn lemma by Keith Conrad.)

Suppose that, on the contrary,
$$\chi_A=\sum_{i\in F} c_i\chi_{A_i}$$
for some finite set $F$ and $A,A_i\in\mathcal A$ (where  $A_i\ne A$ for $i\in F$). The set $P=A\setminus \bigcup\limits_{i\in F}(A\cap A_i)$ is infinite.
For any $n\in P$ we have $\chi_A(n)=1$ and $\sum\limits_{i\in F} c_i\chi_{A_i}(n)=0$. So the above equality cannot hold.

---

You can find a proof about dimension of the space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ (together with some basic facts about Hamel bases) here: [Does $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ have a basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/does-mathbbr-mathbbr-have-a-basis)

In fact, it can be shown that already smaller spaces must have dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$, see [Cardinality of a Hamel basis of $\ell_1(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis).

Comment: The idea of using AD families comes from Lacey's paper mentioned in the related thread. (Of course, he shows a different result there, but AD-families are one of the ingredients of his proof.)

Answer (score 3):

I like the following solution (a colleague of mine told me about it):

For any $a\in\mathbb R$ we have a sequence $\widehat a=(1,a,a^2,\dots,a^k,\dots)$.

The set $\{\widehat a; a\in\mathbb R\}$ is linearly independent. (To see this just notice that if you choose $n$ sequences from this set then the first $n$ coordinates of these sequences form [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).)

Thus we have a linearly independent of cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Hence cardinality of any Hamel basis is at least $\mathfrak c$.

At the same time, the cardinality of the whole space is $|\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}|=\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$, so the basis cannot have more than $\mathfrak c$ elements. Thus the Hamel dimension of this space is $\mathfrak c$.